# How can I have my top container position relative to its parent in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding

I cannot seem to find why the padding it not relative to its parent and does not remove the white line

[image]

[image]

```css
body {
  color: #40514e;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #66bfbf;
  font-size: 5.625rem;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  font-family: "Sacramento", cursive;
}

/* review font size on h2*/

h2 {
  color: #66bfbf;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  color: #11999e;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

p {
  line-height: 2;
}

hr {
  border: dotted #eaf6f6 6px;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 4%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

a {
  color: #11999e;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #eaf6f6;
}

/* check this div background-color*/

div {
  background-color: #e4f9f5;
}

/* remember to check the padding on the .top-container*/

.top-container {
  background-color: #e4f9f5;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 562.5%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.middle-container {
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.bottom-container {
  background-color: #66bfbf;
  padding: 50px 0 20px;
}

.pro {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.intro {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}


.contact-message {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 40px auto 60px;
}

.copyright {
  color: #eaf6f6;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  padding: 20px o;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 300px;
  top: 40px;
}

.boiler-plate {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.Cheeseburger {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.btn {
  background: #11cdd4;
  /* background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #22A39F); */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #22a39f);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #22a39f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #22a39f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11cdd4, #22a39f);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8;
  -moz-border-radius: 8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #30e3cb;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #97dece);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #97dece);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #97dece);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #97dece);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30e3cb, #97dece);
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* .bottom-cloud needs further tweaking the cloud8*/

.bottom-cloud {
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.skill-row {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-emphasis: left;
}
```

Comment: Please make minimalistic project on JSFiddle or somewhere. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the desired result?